# Read numbers separated by ":" from file - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having some problems reading some numbers separated by ":" from a txt file in java.

This is what i have so far:

```
    public static void main(String []args) {
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
    String inputFile = keyb.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter output file name: ");
    String outputFile = keyb.nextLine();

    File file = new File(inputFile);

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

        }


    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("File not found!");

    }

}
```

File numbers.txt

```
12.1:15.42
0.23:0.25
-9.2:-8.1
13.5:15.9
1024:1023.9
1.0e-3:1.0e-4
15.92:-9.35
18.26:6.4
55.931:55.930
256:512
```

I dont understand why its not being read...any help would be much appreciated! thank you!

Comment: it terminates...it doesn't get to the while loop..

Comment: Does not find any code for separating the String??

Comment: check your file. there is lines of text existing??

Comment: @RakeshKR i was trying to output the entire .txt file

Comment: @subash i added the .txt to the question

Comment: change the **FileNotFoundException** to simply **Exception**. may be you got some other exceptions.

Comment: @user3000730 Please Check this Link for https://rakeshkr2.snipt.net/java-file-operations differnt file operations

Comment: What is the location of numbers.txt? It should be exactly in the root folder.

Comment: it is in the root folder, @Sandhu. But the thing is if i remove the while loop and just `System.out.println(sc.nextLine());` I get an error saying `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @Sandhu - if the location were wrong, she'd be getting the FileNotFoundException thrown.

Comment: It works for me. check your file path.

Comment: @user3000730 - That's what happens if the file exists but is empty.  Are you sure you saved the file properly?

Comment: @n1234 http://postimg.org/image/68c23457j/

Comment: OP, starting from the root directory, provide the complete path. like if it is in C:\ drive in the folder tmp path will be `C:\\tmp\\numbers.txt` if it is unix system it will be `C:/tmp/numbers.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried testing your program and got correct output. Take a look

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Read {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            File file = new File("numbers.txt");

            try {

                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println("File not found!");

            }
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
12.1:15.42
0.23:0.25
-9.2:-8.1
13.5:15.9
1024:1023.9
1.0e-3:1.0e-4
15.92:-9.35
18.26:6.4
55.931:55.930
256:512
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [`java.util.BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read a file. There generally easy to use compared to the Scanner class.

```
    ...
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

    String inLine; //Buffer used to store the current line
    while ((inLine = br.readLine()) != null) //keep reading until we reach the end of file
    {
        System.out.println(inLine);
    }
```

Tutorial: [`Java >> BufferedReader`](http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/tutorials/java/java11.php)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the split method in the string class and equate the output to an array,each index will have a different number if they are all indeed seperated by the same character that you have specified above: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and http://www.coderanch.com/t/385246/java/java/split-method-String-API might help but I strongly recon u download all the APIs